# Curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the condition $x+y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Yesterday I was wondering if there are (at least continuous) curves $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the condition $x+y \in \mathbb{Q}$ for every $(x,y)\in\mathcal{C}$.

The obvious solutions are the linear equations $y=-x+q$ with $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Are there other obvious curves that I'm missing or is it possible to prove the there are no other?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ I presume?

Comment: Aren't these just a bunch of slope $-1$ lines with rational intercepts? Obviously this cannot be true for every $x,y\in\Bbb R^2$, you just pick $x=0, y=\pi$ so I assume you just mean for things in the curve.

Comment: I'm looking for continuous curves with x and y in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @koteth obviously if all $x,y$ in the curve **also** satisfy $x+y\in\Bbb Q$ then the curve is a subset of unions of such lines, by definition of what it means to satisfy that equation.

Comment: @Mathematician 42, not at all for sure.

Comment: suggest the 1st step: move the  problem to higher dimension and investigate the probabilities of a surface $z=x+y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a bit about connected components: The set $P=\left\{(x,y):x+y\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$, which is the union of all lines $y=-x+q$ for $q$ rational, has precisely these lines as connected components, so these are in fact all "curves" which satisfy the equation $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: My doubt was if there are other families of curves besides $P=\{(x,y):x+y\in\mathbb{Q}\} $

Comment: @koteth $P$ is only a set which is useful in trying to solve your problem, because the curves which satisfy $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$ are all subsets of $P$. My answer (as well as BrL's, which I admit to be more elegant) shows that the only possibility for a curve $C$ to satisfy $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $(x,y)\in C$ is if it is of the form $C=\left\{(x,y):y=-q+x\right\}$ for a certain fixed $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ (maybe consider only $x$ in an interval).

Comment: @Luiz Cordeiro I don't know if my answer is elegant but after some reflexion yours is much more general ! You have shown that being a curve does not matter and that the only connected subsets of $\mathbf{R}^2$ satisfying the desired property are exactly the "intervals" contained in one of the aforementioned lines.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it depends on what you call a continuous curve. If you mean an object defined in a parametric way $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ where $x$ and $y$ are two continuous functions on an interval $I$ then $x+y$ is also a continuous function on $I$. But by the intermediate value theorem, if you require $x+y$ to take values in $\mathbf{Q}$ then it forces this function to be contant. Thus you only have lines.